# Can I use Windows Azure Notification Hub to send push notification from Windows 8 to Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1, azure-notificationhub

I created an ASP.NET MVC 4 app which can send toast notifications to Win 8 and WP 8 as well.
My (maybe silly) question is that can I use Notification Hub to sent from Win 8 to WP 8 / WP 8 to Win 8?
If not, I have to use Mobile Services?

Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that ist is not possible to install `Azure.ServiceBus` package in Windows Store apps, which would permit to easily send notifications through Notification Hub.

However, if you have the Push Channel Uri you can send them directly through **MPNS**. The only thing you need to do is to create an HTTP request with the appropriate headers and body.

You will find the instruction in the following link:

[Sending push notifications for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202945%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: I create my back end with Windows Azure so I will do the pushing via Mobile Services.

Comment: Is there a limitation to the number of push notifications that may be sent over a period of time? I'd like to be able to create some sort of mass push notification service for my users, and send them all a notification simultaneously and instantly. User base is very large.